# Rendering LaTeX equations at Github Wiki

Tags: embedding

Is there a reliable way to render LaTeX equations at my Github Wiki wikipages? I have used the Codecogs LaTeX Eqn Editor but I am facing some problems now, namely the incorrect rendering of the equations.

Thanks in advance

PS I know that this question is not directly oriented to LaTeX itself.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11256433/2442087 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12502440/2442087.  See also https://github.com/github/markup/issues/274